# RESNET50 Input to reshape is a tensor with 1638400 values, but requires a multiple of 25088

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I have a dataset with 2513 images of 8 classes and I want to fine tune ResNet50 on it. This is my code:

```py
import keras
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tensorflow.keras.applications.resnet50 import ResNet50
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Activation, Reshape, Conv2D, Flatten, GlobalAveragePooling2D, Dropout
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import SGD, Adam, Nadam

DATA_DIR = 'data/'

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    #rescale=1./255,
    #shear_range=0.2,
    #zoom_range=0.2,
    #horizontal_flip=True,
    validation_split=0.3
    )

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(DATA_DIR,
    batch_size=50,
    class_mode='categorical',
    subset='training')

validation_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    DATA_DIR, # same directory as training data
    batch_size=50,
    class_mode='categorical',
    subset='validation') # set as validation data

#X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.20, random_state=33)



base_model = ResNet50(weights='imagenet', include_top=True)

head_model = base_model.get_layer("conv5_block1_1_conv").output
    
head_model = Dense(512, activation="relu")(head_model)
head_model = Dropout(0.5)(head_model)
head_model = Flatten()(head_model)
#base_out = Reshape((25088,))(base_out)
head_model = Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")(head_model)
# place the head FC model on top of the base model (this will become
# the actual model we will train)
model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=head_model)
model.summary()
# loop over all layers in the base model and freeze them so they will
# *not* be updated during the first training process
for layer in base_model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False
    
    
# sgd = SGD(lr=lrate, momentum=0.9, decay=decay, nesterov=False)
adam = Adam(lr=0.001)
model.compile(optimizer= adam, loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch = train_generator.samples // 32,
    validation_data = validation_generator, 
    validation_steps = validation_generator.samples // 32,
    epochs = 100)

model.save("asd.h5")
```

But running this it throws this error:

> InvalidArgumentError:  Input to reshape is a tensor with 1638400 values, but the requested shape requires a multiple of 25088
> [[node model_8/flatten_7/Reshape (defined at ..)

What I have to do to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a couple of things that seems you need to consider or ensure. First, you load `ResNet50` with its `weight` and `include_top` argument but didn't define the `input_shape` and by that, it goes with a default value of (`224, 224, 3`) and at the same time, you define your generator in `flow_from_directory`, you also didn't set `image_size` and [by default](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/85c8b2a817f95a3e979ecd1ed95bff1dc1335cff/tensorflow/python/keras/preprocessing/image_dataset.py#L99) it set `(256, 256)` with `color_mode = rgb`. So, it seems like there is probably an input shape missmatch issue that you need to look at it. [Check](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43012341/9215780) this also.

Second, as you mentioned you have **8** classes to classify and set loss function to `categorical_crossentropy` for your model, then your last layer should be more like this:

```
# head_model = Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")(head_model) # No
head_model = Dense(8, activation="softmax")(head_model)   # Yes
```

After we ensure these details, the model should run as expected.

```
from tensorflow.keras.applications import ResNet50
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten
from tensorflow.keras import Model 

base_model = ResNet50(weights='imagenet', include_top=True)
head_model = base_model.get_layer("conv5_block1_1_conv").output
head_model = Dense(512, activation="relu")(head_model)
head_model = Dropout(0.5)(head_model)
head_model = Flatten()(head_model)
head_model = Dense(8, activation="softmax")(head_model)
model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=head_model)

import numpy as np 
img = np.random.randint(0, 255, size=(2, 224, 224, 3))
model.compile(optimizer= 'adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', 
               metrics=['accuracy'])
pred = model.predict(img)
pred.shape
(2, 8)
```